# Oracle function without cursor or loop

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

hi guys i need to know if exist a way to create a function in oracle that return all rows from a query like that "SELECT * FROM FOO" without CURSORS or LOOPS

Comment: what should be the type returned by the function?

Comment: The supporting tags seem to suggest you have a specific requirement in mind. Perhaps you should add some details to your question so we can better understand what you're driving it.

Answer (score 0):

... well, function below does not use cursors nor loops and returns data from table. I used `bulk collect`.

```
create table t(id, name) as (select 1, 'PQR' from dual union all select 2, 'XYZ' from dual);
create type tr as object (id int, name varchar2(10));
create type tt as table of tr;

create or replace function test return tt is
  v_ret tt;
begin
  select tr(id, name) bulk collect into v_ret from t;
  return v_ret;
end;

select * from table(test);
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME
--- ----------
  1 PQR
  2 XYZ
```

Comment: ref cursor not possible here?

Comment: @Gaj - what do you have in mind? Remember that the question stipulates *without CURSORS or LOOPS* , which could reasonably be interpreted to exclude ref cursors too. Although as the requirement appears fake (probably homework or interview question) I suppose it doesn't really matter.